# "make clean" doesn't clean dependencies with Automake?

Tags: git, dependencies, makefile, automake

I have a C++ project which uses Autoconf and Automake. I decided that there are too many source files in my `src` directory, and moved some files to a subdirectory. Then, I modified the `Makefile.am` and changed these files from `source.cpp` to `subdir/source.cpp`. I knew this approach should work, as I did this before for some new files (but then I didn't rename anything). Now I ran the following, as usual:

```
autoreconf
./configure
make clean
make
```

I got an error message of something like this:

```
No rule to make target "source.cpp" needed for "source.o"
```

I didn't understand what went wrong. I checked my Makefile, but it seemed to be right. So I cloned my git repository to a new place, and tried a make there, and it worked. No problem, thought I, and did a `git clean -xf` on my original directory. After this, compilation still didn't work. Now I did a diff on the two directory stuctures (after another `git clean -xf`, and found that there remained a `.deps` directory. After deleting that, it compiled.

The moral of the story is the following:

- `make clean` doesn't delete dependencies.
- `git clean -xf` doesn't delete dependencies (probably because of the hidden directory).

Is there any way to make `make clean` (or possibly `git clean`) remove this directory automatically? Sure I can do it manually, but it is very annoying that there are dependency files left after a clean.

Comment: Running `autoreconf` after editing `Makefile.am`, or removing `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` from `configure.ac`, might solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make clean` just does whatever the clean target in your makefile is.  If you want to remove the `.deps` directory, add

```
clean::
        rm -rf .deps
```

to the Makefile.

If you want `git clean` to do this for you, just add the `-d` flag:  `git clean -fxd` will also clean out untracked subdirectories.

Comment: The git clean -d solution worked. The one with the Makefile doesn't seem so straightforward to me though. Since I use Automake, I don't think I can just simply redefine rules. Maybe there is a way, but since the dependency files were created by the automatically generated Makefile, I think there should be a way to remove them without hacking.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there any way to make make clean (or possibly git clean) remove this directory automatically?

Use `make distclean` instead of `make clean` which will remove `.deps`.

Comment: This is especially useful if you're using automake and don't want to manually edit your Makefile.

Comment: I think this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to run `git clean -xf`, you should be willing to run `git clean -xfd`.

From `git help clean`:

> `-d   Remove untracted directories in addition to untracted files.`